# Uploaded image has 0 bytes

Tags: php, image, upload

I´m using html2canvas to screenshot div and upload it to the server via PHP. Console is saying that

> 277ms html2canvas: Canvas renderer initialized (208x311 at 243.71250915527344,159.40000915527344) with scale 1.25

so it looks like it´s working, but when PHP upload an image to the server, it has 0 bytes and it can´t be opened.

PHP:

```
<?php
$data = $_REQUEST['base64data'];
$image = explode('base64,',$data);
file_put_contents('1.jpg',base64_decode($image[1]));
?>
```

jQuery:

```
<script>
function takeScreenshot(){
var element = jQuery("#vpc-components")[0];
html2canvas(element,{
background:'#FFFFFF',
onrendered:function(canvas){
var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1.0);
$.ajax({
url:'/wp-content/plugins/html2canvas/save.php',
type:'post',
dataType:'text',
data:{base64data:imgData}
});
}
});
}
</script>
```

Any idea?

Comment: _“but when PHP upload an image to the server”_ - it’s not PHP _uploading_ the image to the server, at most PHP is _processing_ the upload _on_ the server side. Where the actual upload happens, you neglected to show us (client-side code.)

Comment: @CBroe I´m sorry, I have edited the question...could this help?

Answer (score 0):

in your case I would use the developer tools of your favourite browser and inspect the "Network" Tab.

Inspect the XHR-Request (in chrome: Ctrl+J), then Network Tab

Then you can easy see whether there is actually any data transferred to your server.

Add some debugging on the server side additonally , for example

```
var_dump($_FILES);
var_dump($_REQUEST);
```

And then replay the Network request (right click on XHR-Request in Network-Tab and "Replay XHR")

This way you can easily check if your data is transmitted and you can adujst your server processing.

[XHR request insepction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6j9D.png)